# how to pass state to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I created MExample component in that component  i have created this

```
export default class MExample extends Component {

   _validate() {
          if (validateDate(this.state.choseDate).status) {
          if (validateList(this.state.list).status) {
           var list = this.state.list;
           var choseDate = this.state.choseDate;
           console.log(list+choseDate)
                this.setState({ visibleModal: null , list:[], choseDate:''})
            } else {
                alert("select list date")
             } 
           } else {
            alert("select monthly date ")
          }
      } 
 render() {
   return (
    // jsx
   )}

export default class Mnavigate extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <MExample list={this.state.list} choseDate = {this.state.choseDate}/>
      // can i access value like this ?
    )
  }
```

How to use `this.state.list` and `this.state.choseDate` in other component in which i'm importing this component `<MExample here i want list and choseDate value />`

Comment: <MExample list={this.state.list} choseDate={this.state.choseDate} />

Comment: ok can i check here value coming or not in console.log ?

Comment: yes you can. in the MExample component just type console.log(this.props.list) if the component is a class component or console.log(props.list) if it is a function component

Comment: @rushabh check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639498/6544460

Answer (score 2):

```
<MExample list={this.state.list} choseDate={this.state.choseDate} />
```

and inside `MExample` component

access through 
`this.props.list` and `this.props.choseDate`

```
class MExample extends React.Component{
         render(){
          console.log(this.props.list);
          return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create properties and pass them as props.

```
Create a component as below 



 import React, { Component } from 'react'

        class MExample  extends Component {

                   // You can access them via this.props

                validate = () => {
                 console.log(this.prop.list);
                 console.log(this.prop.choseDate);
                } 
                render() {
                   let {list,choseDate} = this.props;            

                    // your code comes here
                    return (
                        <div>

                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }

    export default MExample;
```

Pass the state in the properties.

```
<MExample list={this.state.list} choseDate={this.state.choseDate} />
```